# Is an API available for the new Google sheets (spreadsheets)?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

With the introduction of the new version of the Google sheets (spreadsheets), the Gdata API no longer work. (see https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3543688) Are there new APIs available for the new Google sheets or will Gdata be updated to support the new Sheets? Or are there any workarounds?

This is currently breaking our production code which programmatically reads contents from Google Sheets using the gdata API. Please help!

Comment: I assume you know about google apps script.

Comment: Any news from Google about this? I can't find a single post from Google mentioning gdata api support with the new sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Google has finally updated their Gdata APIs to work with the new sheets now. Notice that the page: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3543688 has removed the line about Gdata not working.

I have also tested this and it seems to be working for us now.

Comment: But it doesn't support yet the Python3 version. :(

Comment: @Wilson When you tested, what did you use? .... I tested with Java and Java now works. But sounds like there might be bugs.

Comment: I'm using the python gdata client lib (https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) with python 2.7. Seems to be working for us.

Comment: The current python 2.7, 2.0.18, client cannot successfully execute UpdateRow against new sheets. I've patched the client locally so that UpdateRow works, but I'm still seeing excessive 500 and 400 errors on InsertRow and DeleteRow with the python client when running side by side tests of identical data in old sheet vs new sheet. Old sheet has 0 errors and new sheet has about 10% error rate.

Comment: Python users of new google sheets should follow this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=692

Comment: Python users: In the new sheets api, Google changed the semantics of the SpreadsheetsListFeed when calling DeleteRow on an item in the feed. If you call more than one DeleteRow on a feed, subsequent DeleteRow requests will throw 400 error w/ bad row_id. All the subsequent 'link' href attributes of the rows have to be shifted by one after each Delete operation in the feed. This was the source of all the 400 and 500's I was seeing yesterday with DeleteRow requests. This behavior only exists in the new sheets api.

Answer (score 1):

Can create old style sheets at http://g.co/oldsheets
Painful to do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

Google say: "However, there are a handful of features that are **still in development** and not yet available."
 the list **includes Gdata**

....
"There are also a few features that we'll be **retiring** in the new Google Sheets" ... the list does **not include Gdata**.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3543688

**Switching back:** If you switch back to old style sheets, it will ask you why and you can leave a comment.
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3544847#workarounds